# Qt: updating database model through view

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, model-view

I encounter a strange behavior when I try to update an SQLite database through a view. Depending on which edit strategy I use, I can either update the view, or update the database, but I don't manage to update the database and have the view display the new value.

Essentially, I use the following code:

```
auto sdb = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
sdb.setDatabaseName("database.db");

QSqlTableModel *model = new QSqlTableModel(0, sdb);
model->setTable("table");

//model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange);
model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
model->select();

QTableView *tv = new QTableView();
tv->setModel(model);
tv->show();

// I'm not sure, this connect statement is needed.
// Either way, it does not change the behavior of the problem I observe
connect(model,
        SIGNAL(dataChanged(const QModelIndex &,
                           const QModelIndex &,
                           const QVector<int> &)),
        tv,
        SLOT(dataChanged(const QModelIndex &,
                         const QModelIndex &,
                         const QVector<int> &)));
```

When I use `QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit`

The view changes, but the underlying database does not get updated. I.e. restarting the application (or reloading the database) does not have the field updated. Which is obvious I guess, because I would have to manually 'submit' the changes to the underlying DB.

When I use`QSqlTableModel::OnFieldChange`

After hitting enter after editing the view, the view (for the edited row) becomes blank. The underlying DB gets updated, I can see that in the DB, but somehow the view does not get the new value.

Comment: I haven't used databases with Model/View,  but my advice: If things get weird and  you don't know how to proceed, consider  creating a delegate and handle data edits manually.

Comment: What platform are you on? some DB driver plugins on minor platforms are quite buggy

Comment: My minor platform is Linux (RedHat). Using a delegate seems to be a good advice! Unfortunately, it still shows the same behavior.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I got it to work by using a delegate, but unfortunately, it still does not work. With the delegate emitting signals, the view (and the changes) look OK, right after editing. But when moving focus away from the cell, the whole table row becomes empty again, same as before. -- In case it is a problem of the DB driver, do you think there is any chance I can fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was the missing 'PRIMARY KEY' on one of the columns in the SQLite database. Through editing the view, the database could be successfully updated but somehow the changes did not get properly forwarded to the view

Creating a new table with one of the columns being the primary key, solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it turned out the delegate was not needed. Simply making one of the SQLite columns PRIMARY KEY, made the QSqlTableModel work nicely with the model/view interface of Qt.